# error in sparse model matrix

Tags: r, metrics, xgboost

I am programming here in R (Shiny app).

I have a problem in modelling xgboost model:

I have this data:

```
> data
  #var1 var2 var3 y
1     1    2    3 1
2     2    3    4 0
3     3    4    7 0
4     4    6    8 1
```

The Data I would like to use for prediction

```
> pred.data
  #var1 var2 var3
1     1    2    3
2     4    6    5
3     2    4    7
4     1    3    4
```

I want to use xgboost while y is the target variable, so I start by using sparse model matrix.

```
loop.vars<-c("#var1","var2","var3")
myform <- as.formula(paste(" ~ ", paste(loop.vars, collapse= "+"),"-1")) 
Data<-sparse.model.matrix(myform,data)
```

here I get the error:

```
 Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
      <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
    1:  ~  #var1+var2+var3 -1
      ^
```

so I tried to add brackets

```
fun <- function(x) paste0("`", x, "`")
myform <- as.formula(paste(" ~ ", paste(fun(loop.vars), collapse= "+"),"-1")) 

> myform
~`#var1` + var2 + var3 - 1
```

sparse.model.matrix(myform,data)

```
Error: fnames == names(mf) are not all TRUE
```

How can I solve this without changing the column names?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it just the special character `#`, removing/replacing this seems to solve the problem for me

Comment: @timfaber, the OP wrote that he can't remove the # character so he is looking for a workaround that will let him use this character  (I'm guessing, also other special characters) inside XGB.

Comment: The same problem exists also when the name starts with a number, and not just  #, and i don't know if there are another characters which give the same problem.

Comment: i am trying to find out a way to solve this without changing the column names which i get from the user